# Pinning a folder to Pinata (IPFS) using PHP doesn't work but individual files do

Tags: php, arrays, curl, pinata

I have a script that uploads files to Pinata using cURL & PHP, it works great. But now im trying to pin an entire folder of files. I followed the little instructions they give but get -

```
[error] => Invalid request format.
```

Instructions

```
https://docs.pinata.cloud/pinata-api/pinning/pin-file-or-directory
```

It says to append files to an array which I do, but it wants the key of the array to be "file" and the array cant have the same key value for multiple files.

Here is my array -

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [0] => CURLFile Object
                (
                    [name] => 1662838796/playlist0.ts
                    [mime] => 
                    [postname] => 
                )

            [1] => CURLFile Object
                (
                    [name] => 1662838796/playlist1.ts
                    [mime] => 
                    [postname] => 
                )

            [2] => CURLFile Object
                (
                    [name] => 1662838796/playlist2.ts
                    [mime] => 
                    [postname] => 
                )

        )

)
```

In order to keep "File as the main index I added int keys to each file but still no luck. If I use this single value array it pins the file and works as expected. -

```
Array
(
    [file] => CURLFile Object
        (
            [name] => 1662838796/playlist2.ts
            [mime] => 
            [postname] => 
        )

)
```

Any idea where im going wrong here?

cURL Request -

```
$files = [
    '1662838796/playlist0.ts',
    '1662838796/playlist1.ts',
    '1662838796/playlist2.ts',
];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $postData['file'] = curl_file_create($file);
}

$url = "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result, true); 

// returned CID
$hash = $json['IpfsHash'];
```

** Edit
If I remove the "file" and just use index keys I get -

```
[error] => Unexpected field
```

Not sure if thats going in the right direction or wrong direction but its a different error so might help find the issue.

Comment: Piñata is really having a crap api, they still couldn’t fix issue I posted like 6 month ago lol about pining folders, I end up pining files one by one

Comment: Yeah I'm noticing that. Can you do them one by one into a folder? I need all these files in the same folder because it's a HLS video for streaming. But I guess I could do them one by one as long as they're hosted in the same dir. @antokhio

Comment: Yea there is a method, using rest, but I need to check on project and I’m off the pc right now…

Comment: @antokhio any luck finding the rest method?

Comment: Hi I checked it quickly in the morning and it was few messy scripts without any idea witch one is the one, I’ll try to test them and check few more projects and will try to push you a gist in the morning

Comment: There is this also, but not sure if you can use it for backend https://www.npmjs.com/package/pinata-upload-cli it looks new :)

Comment: @antokhio ok thats cool thank you! it might just work, im going to test it out now

Comment: @antokhio ok yeah after some permissions hassle I got this to work in the browser. Thank you for the tip, if you'll ad it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Cool nice to know it worked, will try to write something in the morning ;) cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $postData['file'] = curl_file_create($file);
}
```

The only $file that will be in the $postData is the last one in the the $files array.  `1662838796/playlist2.ts`.  Possibly you meant to do it this way:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $postData['file'][] = curl_file_create($file);
}
```

> I have the request header set "Content-Type: application/json",
> Because you have that header the $postData will go to the BODY and the $_POST global will have nothing.  The word array may turn up in the BODY.

Either you remove the JSON header, or you change the $postData to JSON.
Which depends what the app wants.
Try one and if it does not work try the other.

The easy one would be to remove the content type form $headers.  Do not send any content type. 
When not content type is specified when curl sees an array in the post data, it will change the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

**END OF UPDATE**

---

---

I see you have `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`
Do you have the HTTP request header have a "Content-Type: application/json"?

Try this if you want.  I have a page I use to see what is being sent. 
Change the url to this page and it will show you what is being sent.
For example if your header has "Content-Type: application/json" the POST data will not be in the form data it will be in the request body.  that would be if the $postData were a json string.  The data should be an array like you have, but the Content-Type: must be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
If you include another content type else in the $request it will be sent rather then the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You could post the contents of your $headers array.

[Link to Get HTTP request headers and data](http://eatled.com/receiveheader.php)

This is the code for receiveheaders.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
echo "\nBODY\n";
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "\n\$_POST\n";
var_export($_POST);
echo "\n\$_FILES\n";
var_export($_FILES);
echo "\n\$_SERVER\n";
var_export($_SERVER);
```

And if you click on it, the response will look similar to this.

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Dnt: 1
Host: eatled.com
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0

BODY

$_POST
array (
)
$_FILES
array (
)
$_SERVER
array (
  'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/home3/el/public_html',
  'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => '',
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/home3/el/public_html',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'no-cache',
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive',
  'HTTP_DNT' => '1',
  'HTTP_HOST' => 'eatled.com',
  'HTTP_PRAGMA' => 'no-cache',
  'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => '1',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0',
  'PATH' => '/bin:/usr/bin',
  'QUERY_STRING' => '',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => '173.169.76.167',
  'REMOTE_PORT' => '61212',
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'REQUEST_SCHEME' => 'http',
  'REQUEST_URI' => '/receiveheader.php',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/home3/el/public_html/receiveheader.php',
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/receiveheader.php',
  'SCRIPT_URI' => 'http://eatled.com/receiveheader.php',
  'SCRIPT_URL' => '/receiveheader.php',
  'SERVER_ADDR' => '23.111.132.114',
  'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'webmaster@eatled.com',
  'SERVER_NAME' => 'eatled.com',
  'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
  'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache',
  'TZ' => 'America/New_York',
  'UNIQUE_ID' => 'Yx1X9nNaf-LlLkU6uxWSgAAAABQ',
  'PHP_SELF' => '/receiveheader.php',
  'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1662867446.909621,
  'REQUEST_TIME' => 1662867446,
  'argv' =>
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I have the request header set "Content-Type: application/json", I ran the request script you provided but it doesn't give me much info that helps figure out my issue, it shows the data being sent as expected.

Comment: Did anything show up immediately after BODY and before $_POST?  Was anything in the post array.

Comment: Ah ok yeah I have a print_r() so I was seeing the array, This is what I see - $_POST
array (
)
$_FILES
array (
)

Comment: Those fields are also empty when I pin a file successfully

Comment: Thank you, Yeah i've tried it both ways and still getting invalid format. Thats the issue, nobody knows what Pinata wants and they don't do a very good job in their documentation.

Comment: Yeah I was showing that it works in a single value array with file as the key.

Comment: @RyanD And you failed.  You overwrote the previous assignment.  You could have done: ` $postData[$file] = curl_file_create($file);`

Comment: Not sure what you mean I failed, I said in the question it was wrong and cant use the same key. "It says to append files to an array which I do, but it wants the key of the array to be "file" and the array cant have the same key value for multiple files." It was just an example to show the array structure worked.

Comment: @RyanD What I am saying you are NOT appending.  On each loop you overwrite the previous value of `$file`.  Add the second brackets `[]` after the key When the loop finishes, there is only one file in the array.  And you must convert the `postData` to JSON when you use the Content-Type: application/json